# Code Highlighting Control Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm just getting into windows store development. I would like to know if there are any good (preferably free) code highlighting controls available for c#/XAML development on WinRT.

I know there are good ones written in javascript/html, but my app has some complex components, and my c# skills are >>>> than my javascript skills.

I'm good with view only (I don't plan to be editing code in this app at the time being), but edit would be cool too.

Ideally, as lightweight as possible.

Comment: just to clarify, you're writing a C#/XAML app and in that app you're showing code (C#?) and want to highlight it (ala RichText?).  You could, I suppose, try using ones you know about in JS/HTML with the WebView.. the WebView does has some restrictions (less so in 8.1) so not sure how well that would fare.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that route, but I think if I'm going to do that, I'll write the whole UI in HTML/Javascript, and just port it to winrt if needed. I was just hoping for a xaml solution (RichTextBox or w/e). My app integrates with GitHub for viewing code, and wanted a generic code view that supports syntax highlighting, line numbers, and ideally copy. I could go down the road of porting the logic from one of the popular javascript based solutions, just a lot of work.